# Find word that has more than 50 characters

Tags: find, grep

I am trying to use find in combination with grep to find all the php files in my web server which have a word (any sequence of characters except whitespace) with more than 50 characters.

I have this base:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec fgrep -q '.{50}' {} \; -print
```

But is not working as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use `egrep` only:

```
egrep -nor '[^ ]{50,}' .
```

See `man egrep` to understand what is happening in the previous command.

Comment: Thanks for this. My concern is that your command will echo the findings. I want to actully echo the file name as I put in my original question... Can you help me to do that?

Comment: @HommerSmith Please test the command: it will print the file name followed by line number and followed by word. If you want only the filenames, you can use: `egrep -or '[^ ]{50,}' . | cut -d: -f1`

Comment: @HommerSmith Also, if you want only php files, use: `egrep -or '[^ ]{50,}' . | cut -d: -f1 | egrep '*.php$'`

Comment: Yes, but that is inefficient since it will first have to grep all files. The OP's approach using find is better. Also, while looking for non-blank characters is a good idea, `[^ ]` only looks for non-space characters and will match `\t` and `\r` and `\n`. Finally, I recommend `grep -E` instead of the deprecated (see `man grep`) `egrep` which is being phased out.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working as expected because `-q` means `quiet`, it causes `grep` to not print anything, it's only useful when testing the exist status of `grep`. What you want is closer to:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -lP '\w{50,}' {} \;
```

The `-l` means "print the name of the matching file" and `-P` activates perl compatible regular expressions so we can use the `\w` which is shorthand for matching word characters (basically `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]` but the details depend on your locale. Using `[^ ]` is a good idea but will count `\t` and `\r` and even `\n`, as well as stranger things like `~@#$%^&*()` as words and I am assuming that's not what you want.

If you want to match *any* non-space character, use this instead:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -lP '\S{50,}' {} \;
```